# Automatic Centering Of Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

Everytime I add a Gallery in a post, I need to modify the html from

```
[gallery type="rectangular" link="none" ids="1743,1742,1741"]
```

to

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;">
[gallery type="rectangular" link="none" ids="1743,1742,1741"]
</div>
```

I want to modify the php file to have this extra html added. Is this possible to do? I have limited knowledge on php and am struggling to find where this gallery tag is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gallery gets generated in a `<div>` with `class="gallery"` and some variable classes, depending on the gallery settings. See [wp-includes/media.php#L1046](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1046).

So, you can simply add the following style in your stylesheet (styles.css), or using a plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/).

```
.gallery { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

If your theme is responsive, I would suggest to also set the maximum width to 100% to make sure it fits smaller screens as well.

```
.gallery { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Do note that since you specifically add "rectangular" as type, you might want to use a different class than gallery to make sure the styles do not get applied to other galleries.

To verify which class can be used, you can inspect the gallery in your browser:

- Hover over the gallery,
- click on right mouse button and select 'inspect element'.

I hope that helps. GL!